# Strange crashes at ios 13 in background - cow_cleanup

Tags: ios, ios13

i got several crashes in my crashlytics, all crash happened at ios13 and background, my app did request location in background
this is crash logs

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x184da7150 objc_release + 16
1  CoreUI                         0x191d3bd40 -[_CUIInternalLinkRendition dealloc] + 40
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18509511c cow_cleanup + 168
3  CoreFoundation                 0x184f3f438 -[__NSDictionaryM dealloc] + 144
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x184da86e0 AutoreleasePoolPage::releaseUntil(objc_object**) + 180
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x184da85d8 objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 224
6  FrontBoardServices             0x18a108100 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 240
7  FrontBoardServices             0x18a122d84 __88-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:updateWithSettingsDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 184
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x184d32184 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x184cdb038 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 224
10 FrontBoardServices             0x18a147540 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 40
11 FrontBoardServices             0x18a14720c -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible] + 404
12 FrontBoardServices             0x18a147734 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28
13 CoreFoundation                 0x184fe27e0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
14 CoreFoundation                 0x184fe2738 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 80
15 CoreFoundation                 0x184fe1ed0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
16 CoreFoundation                 0x184fdd01c __CFRunLoopRun + 1080
17 CoreFoundation                 0x184fdc8bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
18 GraphicsServices               0x18ee48328 GSEventRunModal + 104
19 UIKitCore                      0x1890726d4 UIApplicationMain + 1936
20 FoodyNowPartners               0x100c6b564 main + 20 (PushManager.swift:20)
21 libdyld.dylib                  0x184e67460 start + 4
```

Comment: Same here. Did you found a cause/solution?

Comment: A have the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Same here. Did you found any solution @ArturJ